# Unable to copy paste files from Ubuntu to windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, copy-and-paste

I was easily able to copy paste files from Ubuntu Downloads folder to any of the other partitions. But now it says, it has read-only permissions. I have windows installed alongside Ubuntu.

Something weird happened yesterday at the time of Booting Ubuntu, the following error was given off:

> DMAR: [Firmware Bug]:  No firmware preserved region can cover this 
> RMRR [0x00000000007b800000-0x000000007ffffffff],contact BIOS vendor for fixes

Error image:
[image: error image]

I was able to solve this by using the command

```
fsck -y /dev/sda10.
```

Upon completion it showed there are 0.6% non-contiguous locations in hard drive, whereas earlier the number was 0.03%. Is this something to worry about?

Secondly, is this somehow related to not being able to copy paste files from Ubuntu to other partitions?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You solved one problem using `fsck`. You will probably also solve other problems with checking the file systems. 'ntfs' file systems, as used by Windows, in linux are only mounted with both read and write permissions provided the file system is "clean". Thus, load your Windows system, and have all file systems checked using the Windows file system check tools. Then *shut down Windows completely*. After that, you will be able to paste on Windows partitions.

To make sure you keep it that way:

- Turn off "Fast start" in Windows. That way, Windows will always fully close partitions when shutting down.
- Always shut down Windows *completely* before using Linux, i.e. no "sleep" or "hibernate".

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked. However upon opening disk utility, I found that there are 64 bad sectors on my hard drive. What should I do about that?

Comment: Feel free to search the site, and if no question found, add another question on this site.This one was about not being able to copy/paste on a Windows partition. Limit your questions to one problem at a time. This is no user forum, but a Q&A site aimed to produce Q&A relevant to Ubuntu users at large.